# Concatenating comparisons in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

This is more out of curiosity but is it possible to concatenate comparisons in javascript?

**example:**

```
var foo = 'a',
    bar = 'b';
if (foo === ('a' || bar)) {
    console.log('yey');
}
```

as oposed to...

```
var foo = 'a',
    bar = 'b';
if (foo === 'a' || foo === bar)) {
    console.log('yey');
}
```

---

P.S: When you are comparing the same variable in several conditions, this could be very useful.

Comment: Oops. It's a dupe allright. I actually searched here but couldn't find anything.

Comment: edited so it becomes a little different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (["a", "b"].indexOf(foo) > -1) {
    console.log("yey");
}
```

Though this method is not supported by some old browsers, have a look at the compatibility issues in **MDN** -- there is an easy [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) provided.

Another way, suggested by [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512958/concatenating-comparisons-in-javascript/#comment20232504_14512973) in the comments, is to check if property exists in object:

```
if (foo in {a: 1, b: 1}) {  // or {a: 1, b: 1}[foo]
    console.log("yey");
}
```

Comment: Seems like `if ({a: 1, b: 1}[foo]))` would be a little nicer.

Comment: @Pointy ... or `foo in {a: 1, b: 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this. My favorite is using an array in conjunction with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
if ( ['a', 'b'].indexOf(foo) > -1 ) {
    console.log('yey');
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Haven't thought of using indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

The [Array indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is one solution

Another option is a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
switch (foo) {
   case "a":
   case "b":
      console.log("bar");
      break;
   case "c":
      console.log("SEE");
      break;
   default:
      console.log("ELSE");
}
```

other solutions can also be an object look up or a regular expression.

Comment: Yes. Although this wouldn't work if right side isn't a string or a number.

Comment: @Tivie give an example of what would fail? switch is not limited to strings and numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right. Seems javascript lets you switch/case with variables

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'd use a regex for this:

```
if (^/a|b$/i.test(foo)) {
  ...
}
```